# How to set expenses chart on google docs

Tags: arrays, plot, charts, google-docs, currency

I'm trying to do a line plot in google docs that could use 4 pieces of info.

I have an array like this:

> ```
> \ Who \ How_Much \ currency(like $ or  €) \ When( dd.mm.yyyy) \
>  Jane    20                 $                 21.08.2016
>  Jane    30                 $                 21.08.2016
>  Adam    10                 €                 22.08.2016
>  ...
> ```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W3Uqw4iAlvCvu3_iwARnja2sigb690eJPicX3Tr_UGg/pubhtml <- real array

There are just two people, two currencies, so the plot should contain 4 lines:
each having sum of the money someone had spent on a certain day in a certain currency. **(Jane$, Jane€, Adam$, Adam€)** */ day*

How to do it and is it possible tho have 4 lines having all of that on one chart?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a pivot table.

A pivot table will allow you to summarize this data in a variety of ways.

This link explains how to use pivot tables in Google Sheets: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

If you need more direction, let me know and I will post more details.